# Name of grid in Windows Explorer

Tags: winapi, grid

I'm creating an application and i need name of a grid which used on windows explorer for listing file and directories. Thanks...

Comment: In general, you can use Spy++ to inspect the UI of other applications (or Snoop for WPF apps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [standard Windows ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx).